# $.getJSON calling the wrong URL

Tags: jquery, getjson

I am building what is more or less a Google Calendar but with much more specific functions/features. Like Google Calendar, when a user clicks on an event, I populate a "pop-up" div with an ajax get request. The html that populates that div includes javascript functions particular to the event being viewed. When the user is finished using the pop-up, whether they close it or save changes, I erase the html inside it before hiding it.

Now to the problem:
for a certain event there is a two-step creation process
1) user clicks on the calendar to create a temporary, movable, resizable event, moves it into place, clicks it to see a confirm pop-up which, when confirmed, calls the server to create the event in the database.

```
//(start) and (end) are unix timestamps for the beginning and end of the new event
$.getJSON("/events/add/(start)/(end)", function(data) {
    //server returns whether or not the add was successful...
});
```

Now, once it's been confirmed and the server didn't have any problems saving the new event, the pop-up's html gets erased, the pop-up is hidden, and the calendar refetches events from the server. Like it should be, the new event is now being fed to the calendar from the database.

When the user clicks on the database version, I populate the pop-up with view.ctp (I'm using cakephp), which includes a cancel button and a javascript function "cancel()"

This is where I am at a loss:
I know the button is calling the function correctly, I've tested it several different ways. Within the function is another getJSON request...

```
$.getJSON("/events/cancel/(eventId)", function(data) {
    //server returns whether or not cancellation was successful
});
```

If I've refreshed the page, cancellation works as expected, but if I try to cancel an event immediately after creating it (without first refreshing the page), instead of the "/events/cancel/(eventId)" url being called, "/events/add/(start)/(end)" gets called again.

There are no problems fetching the JSON data (when the correct url gets called). In fact, the error message it returns is the one you'd expect if you tried to add an event that overlaps with an existing event.

Again, I know the right JavaScript function is being called and I know each server-side function is working appropriately. It's simply, for reasons I don't understand, calling the wrong URL.

I'm sorry to make such a story out of this, and I hope I've included enough info. I don't think it's a problem in my code - like I mentioned, a page refresh prevents this problem.

I've tried setting jquery's cache to false. I've tried renaming and relocating my JavaScript functions so as to prevent any potential overlaps. I've tried changing $.getJSON to simply $.get, but the problem is the same every time.

Comment: It's great to explain things thoroughly, but to get really useful help you'll want to show (a lot) more code.

Answer (score 0):

A debugging step would be to change it to

```
var url = "/events/cancel/(eventId)";
alert(url);
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    //server returns whether or not cancellation was successful
});
```

Comment: just tried that, and i had tried other similar things earlier. it alerts the desired url and then somehow just calls /events/add anyway...

Answer (score 0):

> `again, i know the right js function is being called`

How did you verify this?

This could be caused by a number of things. Most of the time it's thanks to some stray click handler, which you can usually get rid of by doing a

```
$('.cancel').unbind('click').click()
```

Or the live/die equivalent.

Once you're past that, console.log each step in that function to figure out where the url is being changed. Start right before the `$.getJSON` request. If it's an incorrect url, move upwards till you get to the point where the url gets switched.

You can't exempt the code just because it works on a refresh, especially since all kinds of things could be going on when you add an event.

More code would be helpful.

Comment: i confirmed it was calling the right function by putting alert()'s throughout it at different points. you're very right about it being brash to exempt my code, i think i've just figured out what i did wrong and my god is it a newbie mistake!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON('/events/add/'+ start +'/'+ end, function(data) {

});   

$.getJSON('/events/cancel/'+eventId, function(data) {

});
```